# What stat do AD Carries need most?

Tags: league-of-legends

On the average AD Carry (with no built-in on-hit effects) which stat is most important? Lifesteal, Attack Damage, Attack Speed, Critcal, or Escapability? Should I try to get items that can cover many of these or just try to focus one or two at first and fill out later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me preface this answer with this highly depends on what your team needs and how the enemy team is building their team comp.  It also will vary on what the metagame is which while has been relatively stable with Bruiser, AP carry, AD carry, support, tanky jungler can change at the drop of a hat especially when players find huge success suddenly with alternate strategies.

If we assume all these things, then the AD Carry is generally counted on by their team to have sustained DPS.  Pure numbers this is a combination of Attack Damage, Critical, Attack Speed, and Armor Pen.  In terms of what items to get, the most widely used endgame items involve Infinity Edge, Berserker Greaves, and Phantom Dancer.  Depending on how the enemy team builds, and the particular AD Champ used, that itself may vary.  However this gives you a good spread to do significant critical damage that occurs 55% of the time, with substantial boost to Attack Damage, Attack Speed, and Movement Speed.

Answer (score 1):

Depends. Here's some examples:

1. Vayne - attack speed, life steal, and move speed. This is why most go Bloodthirster and PD first. The reason is that a huge chunk of her damage comes from her silver bolts.
2. Ad carries with steroids (AS boosts) - damage first in the form of infinity edge, then either BT or PD, followed by Last Whisper if Necessary
3. Ad carries without steroids (caitlyn) - a bit more focus on attack speed
4. Ezrael - attack damage since he has natural attack speed boosts and his q scales hard off his AD
5. Urgot - mana and damage (manamune), then a bit of tankiness due to his ult